# koa router doesn't work, sends 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa2, koa-router

If I send POST such `/image/cover` or `/image/sub/` from client, the router function doesn't work at all so It sends 404. It's supposed to work but I literally have no idea. I never had this case It just doesn't work for no reason.

**router**

```
import Router from 'koa-router'

const router = new Router({ prefix: '/image' })

router.post('/cover', async (ctx, next) => {
    let URLpath = ctx.request.body.files.cover.path
    ctx.body = { url: URLpath }
})

router.post('/sub', async (ctx, next) => {
    let URLpath = ctx.request.body.files.sub.path
    ctx.body = { url: URLpath }
})

export default router
```

**log**

```
  <-- POST /image/cover
  --> POST /image/cover 404 33ms -
```

**import code (UPDATED)**
**router/index.js**
import compose from 'koa-compose'

```
import accountRouter from './account'
import mypageRouter from './mypage'
import imageRouter from './image'
import postRouter from './post'

const routes = [
  accountRouter,
  mypageRouter,
  imageRouter,
  postRouter
]

export default () => compose([].concat(
  ...routes.map(r => [r.routes(), r.allowedMethods()])
))
```

**app.js**

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import serve from 'koa-static'
import logger from 'koa-logger'
import views from 'koa-views'
import session from 'koa-session'
import passport from 'koa-passport'
import bodyParser from 'koa-body'
import path from 'path'

import routes from './routes'
import config from './config'
import form from './util/formidable'

import mongoose from 'mongoose'
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

mongoose
   .connect(config.MONGODB_URI)
   .then(startApp).catch(::console.error)

function startApp() {
    const app = new Koa()
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
    const dist = __dirname + '/views/'
    console.log(form)
    const bpOption = { IncomingForm: form, multipart: true }

    app.keys = ['secret', 'key'];
    require('./util/passport')

    app
      .use(logger())
      .use(serve(dist))
      .use(session({}, app))
      .use(bodyParser(bpOption))
      .use(passport.initialize())
      .use(passport.session())
      .use(views(__dirname+'/views', { extension: 'pug'}))
      .use(routes())

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`[!] Server is Running on ${port}`))
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you import this?

Comment: @AramilRey I just updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need help function:

`// @help function record route table map`

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const resolve = require('path').resolve;

module.exports = function record(router, filename) {
  const routeTable = fs.createWriteStream(resolve(__dirname, filename));
  routeTable.write(`Update Date: ${new Date().toString()}\n\n`);
  for (let len = router.stack.length, i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    const route = router.stack[i];
    routeTable.write(`URL:${route.path}\t${route.methods.join('|')}\n`);
  }
  routeTable.end();
};
```

then you can involve it by

```
const record = require('./record');
record(routeApp, '.routerc')
```

you will get `.routerc` file(route map) with content such as:

```
URL: /a/c/c POST
URL: /b/a/d GET
```

it can help you to solve problem. maybe work. good luck!